# UPS: AWB tracking via web crawling

Tags: c#, excel, httpwebrequest, web-crawler, webclient

### Problem

Here at work, people spend a lot of time tracking AWB (Air way bill) from diferent sources (UPS, FedEx, DHL, ...). So, I was required to improve the process in order save valuable time, I was thinking to accomplish this using Excel as platform with Excel-DNA & C# but I have been trying some tests (crawling UPS) with no success.

### Tests

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track?HTMLVersion=5.0&loc=es_MX&Requester=UPSHome&WBPM_lid=homepage%2Fct1.html_pnl_trk&trackNums=5007052424&track.x=Rastrear");

request.Method = "GET";
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36";
request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8");
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch");
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.Referer = @"http://www.ups.com/";
request.ContentType = "text/html; charset=utf-8";

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
```

#### Or...

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var values = new NameValueCollection();

    values.Add("HTMLVersion", "5.0");
    values.Add("loc", "es_MX");
    values.Add("Requester", "UPSHome");
    values.Add("WBPM_lid", "homepage/ct1.html_pnl_trk");
    values.Add("trackNums", "5007052424");
    values.Add("track.x", "Rastrear");

    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "gzip,deflate,sdch";
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage] = "es-ES,es;q=0.8";
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Referer] = @"http://www.ups.com/";
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36";

    string url = @"https://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track?";
    byte[] result = client.UploadValues(url, values);

    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\UPSText.txt", Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result));
}
```

But none of the above examples worked as expected.

### Question

Is it possible to web-crawl UPS in order to keep a track of AWB?

### Note

Currently, I have no access to UPS API.

Comment: The page you are trying to open redirected me to a logon page so do you perhaps have an authentication issue?

Comment: @barrowc: That's odd, since you can freely check whatever AWB without any registration.

Comment: @barrowc: If you try with the following URL: http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track?HTMLVersion=5.0&loc=en_US&Requester=UPSHome&WBPM_lid=homepage%2Fct1.html_pnl_trk&trackNums=5007052424&track.x=Track, it will succeed with the browser but not via crawling.

Answer (score 0):

I just finished writing my script for it. The trick is that there is another url where you can just include the tracking number in the url and land directly on the page. You will then have to parse the tables as xml tags won't work. Just offset off of a header.

Comment: Can you please share your code? (So I can accept this as an answer?)